Proper way to toggle between portrait and landscape in koma-script
I am a bit puzzled on how to correctly toggle orientations in a koma-scr document. Consider this example using \KOMAoptions (I know about \storeareas but that doesn't change anything afaict):
\documentclass[12pt,pagesize,DIV=calc,headsepline,footsepline]{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}

First page in portrait
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{pagesize,paper=landscape, DIV=calc} 
Second page in landscape
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{pagesize,paper=portrait, DIV=calc} 
Third page in portrait again

\end{document}

This gives a ridiculously small area for the landscape page (the lines are even shorter than in landscape mode) when using pdflatex or lualatex. (latex … && dvip{s,pdf} … have other problems but I am primarily interested in lualatex). I get the warning
Package typearea Warning: Very low DIV value!
(typearea)                DIV values less than 6 result in textwidth/-height
(typearea)                smaller than total marginwidth/-height.
(typearea)                You should e.g. increase DIV, increase fontsize or
(typearea)                change papersize.

while compiling the landscape page. I can use the manual value DIV=12 which makes the landscape page reasonably big but I was under the impression that DIV=calc automagically computes “correct” values. Furthermore, using DIV=12 for the landscape page I get the complaint:
Package typearea Warning: Bad type area settings!
(typearea)                The detected line width is about 52%
(typearea)                larger than the heuristically estimated maximum
(typearea)                limit of typographical good line width.
(typearea)                You should e.g. decrease DIV, (increase fontsize)
(typearea)                or change papersize.

So how am I supposed to do it in the right way in a koma-scr document?
Edit: The answer to the duplicate questions also helps here, however, I'd like to leave my question be as I hadn't found that answer since I didn't care about a change in paper size.

If seems you have either not read or not understood the definition of “correct” (or “good line width”)  in the typearea chapter of the KOMA-Script manuals. The goal is to have “ a line length of 60
to 70 characters, including spaces and punctuation” (section 2.1). A4 landscape is not the best paper format to get this. So you first have to decide, which result you would expect. Than you can either search for a suitable DIV or use \areaset or something like retaining the margins when changing the paper format.

@cabohah That question is indeed similar in that the answer (using package geometry, the class option usegeometry and the \newgeometry{} command) there also helps here. But I only want to change orientation and not also the papersize which is why I hadn't found it. Changing orientation is imho much more common than changing papersize mid document. As to your first comment I need to follow a standard having head and foot lines going from left to right all the way. Landscape is needed for inserting landscape pages from another pdf file.

I read this and thought "you need to write \recalctypearea after each change: \KOMAoptions{pagesize,paper=portrait, DIV=calc}\recalctypearea."

@KeksDose That does not have any effect here.
